# Periodically monitor if record is not updated Using Node & Event & setTimeOut

Tags: node.js, events, caching, timer, promise

Here is my scenario :

1. Every one checks in every five minutes
2. If some one misses , I should be able to keep track of it.
3. If some one misses N number of times a alert should be generated.

Here is what I have implemented so far :

```
var Report = function(attendence) {
  this.attendence = attendence;
  EventEmitter.call(this);
};

util.inherits(Report, EventEmitter);

Report.prototype.addAPSStatsData = function() {

  var attendenceDB = new Report(this.attendence);

  //Promise 
  var prSave = attendenceDB.save();
  var self = this;
  prSave.then(function(data) {

    //emitting event that data has been saved 
    self.emit('attendenceRecieved', data.userName);

    var saveTime = Date.now();
    self.moniterAPSStatsData(data.userName, saveTime);

  }).catch(function(err) {
    self.emit('error', err);
  });
};

Report.prototype.moniterAPSStatsData = function(userName, time) {

  var cacheKey = appConfig.CACHE_KEY_UserTimeInterval + userName;
  var prevTimer = memoryCache.get(cacheKey);

  if(!prevTimer) 
    clearTimeout(prevTimer);

  var timer = setTimeout(this.moniterCallBackAfterInterval, (5 * 60000), userName, time ,cacheKey);

  //Putting timout in cache so later on it can be clearedout if the new attendence comes in 
  memoryCache.set(cacheKey, timer);

};

Report.prototype.moniterCallBackAfterInterval = function(userName, time ,cacheKey) {
  //Removing from cache
  memoryCache.del(cacheKey);

  //Emitting event so next operation can be handeld
  this.emit('ReportNotRecieved');
};
```

- Do you think this is good approach ?
- It will hold in production env ?
- Any alternatives to setTimeOut which can be used here ?

Thank you very much.